# React native navigation Wix Navigation.pop Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):Error: Failed to execute stack command

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

**Description**

I have used react-native-navigation(V2) Wix in my react-native app. I have got error if pop the componentId.

Error::

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Failed to execute stack command. Stack secondScreen not found.
Error: Failed to execute stack command. Stack secondScreen not found.
```

**secondScreen.js**

```
class SecondScreen extends React.PureComponent {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.navigationEventListener = Navigation.events().bindComponent(this);
   }

   componentDidDisappear() {
      Navigation.pop(this.props.componentId)
   }

   render() {
      const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
      return (
         <Text>SecondScreen</Text>
      )
   }
}

export default SecondScreen;
```

Please tell how to remove is warning.

Comment: Can you please give some context to what you are trying to achieve? Popping a stack in `componentDidDisappear` seems like a smell.